# c++ Right way to store a private variable returned by reference

Tags: c++, reference

Consider this class:

```
class example
{

    inline const A& GetA()
    {
        return _a;
    }

private:
    A _a;
};
```

With the following code:

```
example Ex;
A& a = Ex.GetA();
```

_a will be returned by reference without making any copy of _a.

My question is what happens if I drop the reference operator as follows:

```
example Ex;
A a = Ex.GetA();
```

Will `a` be a reference to `_a` or a copy of `_a` will be created?

Comment: Why do you want to grant access to an internal private variable? Isn't there an other solution?

Comment: @Mario, I changed the method in my question to be returning `const`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be a copy, if there is an accessible copy constructor, and a compile error otherwise. A variable is only a reference if you declare it to be one.

Comment: So, in case _a isn't A but an stl container, a copy of the whole container will be created?

Comment: Just to clarify, if you have `A a; a= Ex.GetA()` then you call the copy assignment rather than the copy constructor. Subtle difference but important.

Comment: @Subway: Yes. Whatever the type, the declaration makes a new variable, not a reference; initialising it with a reference will make a copy. In the case of a standard container, that will copy all of the contents.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, you've declared a local variable (not a reference) so you will get a *copy* of the reference value returned from your function.

That said: *Don't do this*. A public non-const method that returns by non-const reference is only one tiny step better than a struct with public members at a complexity cost. Just use the struct with public members and direct access instead OR properly encapsulate your data.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the method in my question to be returning `const`.

Answer (score 0):

You could simple check by this code sample:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A() {
        std::cout << "Creating A from default ctor" << std::endl;
    }
    A(const A &) {
        std::cout << "A copy created!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Example {
public:
        inline A& getA() {
            return _a;
        }

    private:
        A _a;
};

int main() {
Example a;
A aa = a.getA();

return 0;
}
```